# OWASP: Name of attack using leaked credentials

Tags: web, gmail, owasp

I searching to find the name of an Attack.

Attack desc: Using the credential leaked from one site (hacked site) to another web site.
Example: someone hack Gmail and leak 5milion user/pass online. So the attack take this usernames and password already public and try to log in into other websites like FB, Twitter etc.. As most of the user use the same username/password in many sites.

I am searching the exactly name of this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

EWit is right, it's password reuse attack.

Please refer [here](http://ijcsmc.com/docs/papers/August2013/V2I8201342.pdf) for more information regarding this type of attack and possible defense.